# Add token to existing prismjs language

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, prismjs

I'm trying to add to prismjs's markup language, to add a new token as follows:

```
{something}
^\_______/^
|   |     `---punctuation
|   `---variable
`---punctuation
```

So that this code block ....

```
<div class="blah">
  {test} {sit_date_ran}
</div>
```

... would be highlighted as ...

[image: highlight]

... here's what I've tried ...

```
const lang = cloneDeep(languages.markup);

  lang.interpolation = {
    pattern: /^\{.+?\}$/,
    inside: {
      punctuation: /[\{\}]/,
      variable: /^\{(?:)\}$/,
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The token pattern was just too greedy -- easy fix:

```
  lang.interpolation = {
    pattern: /\{.+?\}/,
    inside: {
      punctuation: /[\{\}]/g,
      variable: /\w+/,
    }
  };
```